Easyest way to migrate from bootstrap to tailwind without JS framework
I started migrating from bootstrap 5 to Tailwind but since the beginning I m blocked by javascript lib.
I used bootstrap Javascript to instanciante modals,Dropdown, toaster etc but I can't find a good replacement in tailwind. I tried Flowbite Javascript, Daisy UI et preline but its buggy.
I don't have time to setup (and to learn) a javascript framework like vue.js or other. Is there any light javascript lib that works with tailwind ?
